# Delphi - Find text in large TMemo

Tags: delphi, full-text-search, delphi-7, memo

I have a TMemo which **contains quite a lot of texts**, 80M (about 400K lines).

The TMemo is set with WordWrap = FALSE, there is **no need** to find texts that wrapped in 2 lines.

I need a fast way to find a text, from the beginning, and also find next.

So, I put a TEdit for putting the text to find and a TButton to find the text in the TMemo.

I was thinking to use Pos(), checking line by line, but that will be slow.
And I don't know how to determine the TMemo.Lines[index] for current cursor position.

Anyone can come up with solution?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution from here:
[Search thru a memo in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232709/search-thru-a-memo-in-delphi)

The SearchText() function works, fast, and very fast.
Took couple of seconds to search unique string at the bottom end.

Comment: If you used a rich edit control you could use [`EM_FINDTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788009.aspx) which is wrapped in in the [`FindText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.FindText) method of `TRichEdit`.

Comment: I think using `Pos` function with `TMemo.Lines.Text` property should be faster; though it can possibly find wrapped substring too, I don't think that is a problem.

Comment: Similar question on SO : [search-thru-a-memo-in-delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232709/search-thru-a-memo-in-delphi). I don't know if it's fast, but the answer has a solution for the index position.

Comment: @Serg: You are right. I found a function from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232709/search-thru-a-memo-in-delphi

Comment: Tested the above SearchText() and it was fast, very fast!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little addition to the [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232709/search-thru-a-memo-in-delphi): you can get the line number without selecting the pattern found, like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I, L: Integer;

begin
  Memo1.WordWrap:= False;
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('Windows.pas');
  I:= Pos('finalization', Memo1.Text);
  if I > 0 then begin
    L := SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, I - 1, 0);
    ShowMessage('Found at line ' + IntToStr(L));
// if you need to select the text found:
    Memo1.SelStart := I - 1;
    Memo1.SelLength := Length('finalization');
    Memo1.SetFocus;
  end;
end;
```

Note that line number is zero-based, also you should subtract 1 from `Pos` result to obtain zero-based offset for `SendMessage` and `TMemo.SelStart`.